# Converting a JSON to a Pandas data frame in Python: why is it not working?

Tags: python

I am trying to get a very straightforward bit of information from an API released by NREL (the National Renewable Energy Lab in the US):

https://developer.nrel.gov/docs/transportation/alt-fuel-stations-v1/all/

My script in Python looks like this:

```
import requests
import csv 
import pandas as pd 

full_request = "https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.json?api_key=[TADA]&fuel_type=E85,ELEC&location=NewWestminster"

gotten = requests.get(full_request)
print(gotten.status_code)
print(type(gotten))
json_type = gotten.json()
dicty = json.loads(gotten)
```

In the very last line, informed by previous questions here on Stack Exchange, I thought that maybe I would be converting it to a dictionary that I could then convert it to a dataframe, just something plain and readable. This is what my console output looks like, however:

```
200
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
<class 'dict'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_west_request.py", line 21, in <module>
    dicty = json.loads(gotten)
NameError: name 'json' is not defined
```

So I'm just looking for a quick way to get this into a form where I can put it into a spreadsheet. I confirmed that there was a response. Are some of the funcctions deprecated or something?

Thank you!

Comment: The argument to `json.loads()` must be a string, so it should be `json.loads(gotten.content)`. But that's the same thing as `gotten.json()`, which you used on the previous line.

Comment: The NameError is because you never did `import json`.

Comment: `NameError: name 'json' is not defined` Note that nowhere in your code have you defined `json`, hence the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prowling through the internet, I managed to get to the point I needed by following this post:
https://deallen7.medium.com/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-an-api-endpoint-in-a-jupyter-notebook-f2561f766ca3

Now, my script looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import json 

full_request = "https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.json?api_key=[AHA]&fuel_type=E85,ELEC&location=NewWestminster"
#gotten = requests.get(full_request)
#print(gotten.status_code)
#stg = gotten.json()

gotten = requests.get(full_request)
partytime = gotten.json()
dfr = pd.DataFrame(partytime['fuel_stations'])
print(dfr.head())
```

...and it seems to work now, I can export to Excel, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import the `json` module, you could just do

```py
import requests

url = "https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.json?api_key=DEMO_KEY&fuel_type=E85,ELEC&state=CA&limit=2"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

and get a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'station_locator_url': 'https://afdc.energy.gov/stations/', 'total_results': 16585, 'station_counts': {'total': 46987, 'fuels': {'BD': {'total': 0}, 'E85': {'total': 326}, 'ELEC': {'total': 46661, 'stations': {'total': 16259}}, 'HY': {'total': 0}, 'LNG': {'total': 0}, 'CNG': {'total': 0}, 'LPG': {'total': 0}, ...
```

(I've used the `DEMO_KEY` here.)

But, since you are looking for

> So I'm just looking for a quick way to get this into a form where I can put it into a spreadsheet.

why don't you use the CSV-API (look at the bottom of the site). You could either use Pandas to do

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.csv?api_key=DEMO_KEY&fuel_type=E85,ELEC&state=CA&limit=2"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=None)
```

or

```py
import requests

url = "https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.csv?api_key=DEMO_KEY&fuel_type=E85,ELEC&state=CA&limit=2"
response = requests.get(url)
with open("data.csv", "w") as file:
    file.write(response.text)
```

to get the data into a CSV-file `data.csv`.
(Again with the `DEMO_KEY`.)

Comment: Thank you, the bit about reading the request directly into a CSV was new to me.